# How to throttle a range slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get my slider to not do tons of unnecessary calls when sliding. I tried to use throttle and debounce from lodash with no luck.So I went with a local one (taken from https://codedamn.com/news/javascript/throttling-in-javascript) I made a simpler example: https://codesandbox.io/s/range-slider-gfip2n?file=/demo.tsx

You can see in the console it'll print like 50 times when you slides,I'd like it to only print like once per second or a reasonable amount of time when I slide(I do need things live)

Code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

function valuetext(value: number) {
  return `${value}°C`;
}
function throttle(callbackFn: (arg0: any) => void, delay: number | undefined) {
  let wait = false;

  return (...args) => {
    if (wait) {
      return;
    }

    callbackFn(...args);
    wait = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      wait = false;
    }, delay);
  };
}

export default function RangeSlider(props) {
  const [displayValue, setDisplayValue] = React.useState<number[]>([2, 30]);

  const handleChange = (event: Event, newValue: number | number[]) => {
    setDisplayValue(event.target.value);
    props.setter(event.target.value);
    console.log("Please print like once");
  };
  const callHttpRequest = throttle(handleChange, 3000);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 300, marginTop: 30 }}>
      <Slider
        defaultValue={displayValue}
        value={displayValue}
        onChange={callHttpRequest}
        // onChangeCommitted={(event: any) => props.setter(event.target.value)}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're probably more interested in debounce rather than throttle. The rendered state of the slider component depends on the value supplied to it being updated. If you debounce your call to `props.setter` then the slider won't slide any more. It will be clunky, at best.

Comment: @spender I had tried debounce but it just delayed the calls in a queue rather than reduce the number of call.